# Making a Cascade file for fingertip tracking

Tags: python, xml, opencv, cascade

i was searching the web for a code example an how to track fingertip's using python and opencv.
Finaly i found [this](https://github.com/srvindian/handgesture_fingers_count). I donwloaded it and it seems to work a bit bad because of the cascade file.
Under a Youtube Video from the person who created this code he says that you must make a new cascade file because his is not so good. So here is my question:

How can i make a cascade file that works with this code?

I searched the internet but i found a lot of concepts and words like HAAR cascade and some other.
So how do i can create a cascade xml file on my windows PC.

I hope someone can explain it to me so i can understand it because i am a little new to python.

greetings

Max

P.S.: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you need a lot of training samples. You need opencv_createsamples.exe to make them usable for training. You need opencv_traincascade.exe to create the cascade file. There are tutorials online.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I will try find something